# Efficient way to remove rows with empty column if more than one row already exists

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm developing an app that utilizes SQLite database.

Considering the following data set:

```
1 | TEST1 | <NULL>
2 | TEST1 | TEST1
3 | TEST1 | <NULL>
4 | TEST1 | TEST123
...
```

I want to remove rows with NULL's if there's at minimum one row with TEST1.

In the above example, the wanted result is:

```
2 | TEST1 | TEST1
4 | TEST1 | TEST123
...
```

And for the following example:

```
1 | TEST1 | <NULL>
2 | TEST1 | TEST123
...
```

The wanted result is the same example as above.

As I see it, I have few options:

1. Avoid INSERT statements of rows, if such condition like the first example exists.
2. DELETE rows after they already been inserted.

Can you please advise on how to achieve each of those options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
select t.*
from t
where t.col3 is not null
union all
select t
from t
where t.col3 is null and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.col2 = t.col2 and t2.col3 is not null);
```

That is, select all non-null values.  Then select null values where there is no other value.

If you are deleting rows, then:

```
delete from t
    where t.col3 is null and
          exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.col2 = t.col2 and t2.col3 is not null);
```